# Makefile: Regexp pattern for prerequisite file(s)

Tags: regex, makefile

I am trying to write a make recipe for a cross-compilation of an `asm` file. The thing is, that I want to use a regex as a makefile prerequisite for the output target because these assembly files are generated in a somewhat automatic way.

So, their names follow the following pattern:

```
1_mps.S # i want this to be compiled into 1_mps.elf
2_mps.S # i want this to be compiled into 2_mps.elf
3_mps.S # i want this to be compiled into 3_mps.elf
```

and so on...

I am trying to find the appropriate handling of this somewhat dynamic rule definition in the Makefile documentation but I am a little bit lost and I need some assistance.

So, how can I define a prerequisite for that and also name the output file like that?

So far, I have tried using wildcards and `%` patterns but with no success.

For example:

```
out.elf : %_mps.S, vectors.S, syscalls.c
      ... gcc cross-compiler invocation here...
```

```
out.elf : *_mps.S, vectors.S, syscalls.c
      ... gcc cross-compiler invocation here...
```

Of course, both of these examples are not working but also, they do not yield the respective outfiles. For example even if they would work they would produce the name `out.elf` in all cases (i.e., for every of the `n_mps.S` input files)

My (not-working) attempt:

```
RISCV_EXE_PREFIX         = $(RISCV)/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-

all: %_mps.hex

$_mps.elf: %_mps.o syscalls.c vectors.S
    $(RISCV_EXE_PREFIX)gcc -o $@ \
        -T link.ld \
        -static \
        $^  \
        -I $(RISCV)/riscv32-unknown-elf/include \
        -L $(RISCV)/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib 

%_mps.o : %_mps.S
    $(RISCV_EXE_PREFIX)gcc -march=rv32imcxpulpv2 -c -w -Os -g -nostdlib \
    -I $(RISCV)/riscv32-unknown-elf/include \
    -L $(RISCV)/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib \
    -lc -lm -lgcc

%_mps.hex: %_mps.elf
    $(RISCV_EXE_PREFIX)objcopy --output-target=verilog $< $@

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM_NAME).elf $(PROGRAM_NAME).hex
```

> make: *** No rule to make target '%_mps.hex', needed by 'all'.  Stop.

Comment: I see nothing to explain why you'd need a regex rather than a basic pattern rule.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Your question should remain strictly a question, though you are welcome to post your solution as an answer. (The text is still available from the [revision history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73375669/revisions))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) to compile your source files into object files first and then link object files into ELF object:

```
all : 1_mps.elf 2_mps.elf 3_mps.elf

%_mps.S :
    # Create .S
    touch $@

%_mps.o : %_mps.S
    # Compile .S into .o
    echo "$^" > $@

%_mps.elf : %_mps.o
    # Link .o into .elf
    echo "$^" > $@

.PHONY: all
.PRECIOUS: %_mps.S %_mps.o # Needed because it makes source files with touch.
```

Output:

```
$ make
# Create .S
touch 1_mps.S
# Compile .S into .o
echo "1_mps.S" > 1_mps.o
# Link .o into .elf
echo "1_mps.o" > 1_mps.elf
# Create .S
touch 2_mps.S
# Compile .S into .o
echo "2_mps.S" > 2_mps.o
# Link .o into .elf
echo "2_mps.o" > 2_mps.elf
# Create .S
touch 3_mps.S
# Compile .S into .o
echo "3_mps.S" > 3_mps.o
# Link .o into .elf
echo "3_mps.o" > 3_mps.elf

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Comment: I updated my question with my `Makefile` following your suggestion. But the `pattern` seems not working.

Comment: The pattern itself should work fine, but you can't use the _pattern_ as a prerequisite for `all`. Try something like `all: $(patsubst %.S,%.hex,$(wildcard *_mps.S))`

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to include your `%_mps.hex` pattern rule.

Comment: @ex1led Added a working example for you.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  I have incorporated your suggestions and came up with the edited (in original text) recipe. I do thank you for your suggestions. It was not indeed a trivial task.

Comment: Probably ask a new question with your updated code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @tripleee it was just a `-o $@` missing in the linking step...my bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

My working attempt

```
RISCV            ?= ~/.riscv
RISCV_EXE_PREFIX  = $(RISCV)/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-
LINKER_SCRIPT     = link.ld
CC                = gcc
LFLAGS            = -lc -lm -lgcc -nostdlib 

all: $(patsubst %.S,%.hex,$(wildcard *_mps.S))

%_mps.hex: %_mps.elf
    @echo "@@@@@@@@ BIN2HEX @@@@@@@@"
    $(RISCV_EXE_PREFIX)objcopy \
    --output-target=verilog $< $@

%_mps.elf: %_mps.o syscalls.c vectors.S
    @echo "@@@@@@@@ LINKING @@@@@@@@"
    $(RISCV_EXE_PREFIX)$(CC) \
    -march=rv32imcxpulpv2 \
    -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) \
    -static $^ \
    -I $(RISCV)/riscv32-unknown-elf/include \
    -L $(RISCV)riscv32-unknown-elf/lib \
    $(LFLAGS) \
    -g -w \
    -o $@

%_mps.o : %_mps.S
    @echo "@@@@@@@@ X-COMPILING @@@@@@@@"
    $(RISCV_EXE_PREFIX)$(CC) \
    -march=rv32imcxpulpv2 \
    -c $< \
    -g -w -Os

.PHONY:
clean: 
    @echo "@@@@@@@@ CLEAN @@@@@@@@"
    rm -rf *.elf *.hex
```